# Use of M2M Table and relationship to get specific data in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, relation

I have Table

```
# File : MyRelations.py
ACC_ADD_TABLE = Table('acc_add_rel', METADATA,
    Column('acc_id', ForeignKey('acc.id'),
            nullable=False),
    Column('add_id', ForeignKey('address.id'),
            nullable=False),
    PrimaryKeyConstraint('add_id', 'acc_id'),
    )   

# File : Address.py
class Address(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True,)
    type = Column(String(length=10), nullable=False)

# File : Account.py
class Account(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True,)
    addresses = relationship('Address',
                            secondary=ACC_ADD_TABLE
                            )
#   default_address = relationship('Address',
#                           secondary=ACC_ADD_TABLE,
#                           primaryjoin=and_("ACC_ADD_TABLE.add_id==Address.id",
#                                            "ACC_ADD_TABLE.acc_id==Account.id",
#                                            "Address.type='default'")
#                           )
```

As per the example I want to access the all default addresses in account. I can use [declared_attr](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/extensions/declarative.html?highlight=declared_attr) or can write the function but is there any way to combine `Table` and `Class` attribute in single `and_` operation?

**Note: Address.py and Account.py both are different files and due to cycle dependency I cant import any model in other model**

Thx for you help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works without requiring an import:

```
default_address = relationship('Address',
                       secondary=ACC_ADD_TABLE,
                       primaryjoin="acc.c.id==acc_add_rel.c.acc_id",
                       secondaryjoin="and_(address.c.id==acc_add_rel.c.add_id, address.c.type=='default')",
                       #uselist = True,
                       )
```

If you are certain that there is only one default address, you might use `uselist=True` for convenience.
Sometimes I prefer the other structure for such situations though: add a column to the `Account` table: `default_address_id` and build `1-[0..1]` relationship based on this column, still checking that the referenced `Address` is also part of `Account.addresses` M-N relationship.

---

On the side note, a typo: in your (commented) code you should use `==` instead of `=` in `"Address.type='default'"`. This does not solve the problem though.

Comment: Thx @van this is working for me :). I was expecting that you are the first from where I get the answer ;).

Comment: @Lafada: fantastic! Yeah, using SO to stay tuned on the SA topics.